# Windows Input prompt validation only allow alphabet characters and underscore

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

Trying to create a basic username check that only allows letters, numbers and the underscore.. anything else should prompt again for user input...

Honestly doing my head in trying to find some better explanations and examples of doing such a thing with DOS .bat file and findstr, ..the below code doesn't work, still allows symbols like *)(&^*"% to be entered with other allowed characters...

```
:setname
set /P username=Enter Username: %=%
echo.%username% | findstr /R "[a-zA-Z0-9_]" >nul 2>&1
if not ErrorLevel 1 (
echo %username%
goto :proceed
)
goto :setname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:setname
SET "usrname="
set /P usrname=Enter Username: %=%
IF NOT DEFINED usrname GOTO :eof
echo.%usrname%| findstr /R "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]" >nul 2>&1
if ErrorLevel 1 (
 echo %usrname% - OK
) ELSE (
 echo %usrname% - invalid
)
goto :setname
```

Two fundamental bugs:

first, you need to find any character that is NOT a..zA..Z0..9

second, you need to NOT `echo` the `SPACE` into the `findstr` as `space` is always invalid

Note that `set /p` does not set var to [nothing] on ENTER - it leaves var unchanged, hence you can set the user name to a default value.

`USERNAME` is a magic variable - instantiated by the system. Logical variablename, but one of a number of presets it's not wise to alter. Try executing `SET` from the prompt in a new session for a partial list...

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  oh and username being a magic variable ..lol that might explain why when I left the input blank and just pressed [enter] it would set my username to my actual windows account username.. was trying to figure wtf was going on with that aswel :D

Comment: I'm curious: What does `%=%` do? I can't find any difference with or without it.

Comment: @stephan I believe that it's there to apply a space after the prompt. `%=%` should be evaluated to nothing. Personally, I prefer `set /p "var=prompt "`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:input
set "in="
set /p "in=Enter username: "
for /f "delims=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%a in ("%in%") do goto :input
echo "%in%"
```